# Karatsuba Multiplication Rule in dividing a Number in two parts

Tags: computational-mathematics, multiplicative-function

In Karatsuba algorithm for multiplying two numbers, we divide each number into two. For example:

```
 x= 1234
 y= 2456
```

Then 
     a = 12, b = 34, c = 24 , d = 56

What if the digits in each number are not even, or the same? What is the rule in dividing it into two parts?

Example:

```
 x = 12345
 y = 2478
```

or

```
 x = 12456778
 y = 241
```

Please help.

Comment: You take the largest length. All other strategies are not only Karatsuba. You can of course implement tests to avoid/shortcut multiplication by 0 or 1 or other simple factors.